# Laravel Mail - PathToFile variable not found

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am writing this simple code to send a mail with attachment, however, I am not able to pass the path to the file variable.

```
$pathToFile = "Sale-".$id.".csv";

Mail::send(array('html' => 'sales.invoice_template'), $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('test@test.com'); // dummy email
            $message->attach($pathToFile);
        });
```

The above code throws:

```
Undefined variable: pathToFile
```

Also, I tried passing a variable (added $pathToVariable with $message in above closure) to the closure but it throws following error:

```
Missing argument 2 for SaleController::{closure}()
```

It basically doesn't identify any variable outside the closure. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$pathToFile = "Sale-".$id.".csv";

Mail::send(array('html' => 'sales.invoice_template'), $data, function($message) use ($pathToFile)
{
    $message->to('test@test.com'); // dummy email
    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

The instruction:

> use ($pathToFile)

...allows you to use your variable in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing $pathToFile within your closure, the script is looking for $pathToFile to be declared within the closure. As no declaration exists, you see the undefined variable error.

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

To fix it you should be able to pass $pathToFile into your closure, e.g.:

```
Mail::send(array('html' => 'sales.invoice_template'), $data, function($message, $pathToFile)
    {
        $message->to('test@test.com'); // dummy email
        $message->attach($pathToFile);
    });
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I already tried that..it gives "Missing argument 2 for SaleController::{closure}()" error (I will update the question)